# Substance B2M to Blender Workflow

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, shaders

I have decided to work with Substance B2M en use the texture maps in Blender. I want to work with the PBR shaders of Cynicat Pro and connect the Substance maps into the input nodes of the PBR Shaders. I especially want to know which texture maps of Substance (base, normal, height, specular, metallic, ...) are relevant for Blender and if they have the same meaning (like the specular and metallic map) and how to connect these maps to the input nodes.

I am mostly interested in the definitions of the texture maps in both packages and whether or not they match.

After reading the blog of Jason alias @Jtheninja, I set up a node group using the Metallic Shader of Cynical Pro and connect the Substance texture maps.

[image]

Would this make sense for a rusted metal?

[image]

Comment: I think the @jtheNinja has an answer ? https://jtheninja.wordpress.com/2015/02/08/importing-substance-painter-texture-to-cycles/

Answer (score 2):

Cynicat Pro really helped me out with explaining how you can connect the Substance bitmaps to his PBR node groups.

[image]

In the material node group you may notice that :

- when importing a DirectX normal map you have to convert it to Open GL normal map
- the roughness is corrected with power node before connecting it to the shaders (according to JtheNinja" The other thing we need to do is square the roughness value to match the range between SP and Cycles. To do that, add a math node, set it to “power”, connect your roughness map to the top slot, and set the bottom slot to “2.0”."
- the metallic map is a sort of mask that tells blender what is metallic and what is not

This seems a very elegant setup with little fuss and very reusable. Comments ?

Now I also learned that you can download compiled Substance files from Textures.com and open these in Substance Player (free) and tweek the maps before exporting the bitmaps. This next to importing images in B2M and creating your own bitmaps. Apart from some issues with the displacement map it seems to work fine

Comment: Huh. I cannot distinguish diffuse or specular maps in your image. Can you explain what you are doing here? Why this way is elegant? Where you got the information from?

Comment: these maps are in the Dielectric and Metallic Shader (product of Cynicat Pro; see also his youtube series on PBR Shaders). I think it is elegant because you just connect the Substance Maps (both for Dielectric and Metallic materials) and these maps are in fact the handles on your dashboard. And I think this way you have a full PBR workflow

Comment: I know there are nowadays a lot of people that explain PBR and construct PBR shaders but I think the approach of Cynicat Pro is fundamental and clearcut https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xMpDTk3DTW8&list=PLlH00768JwqG4__RRtKACofTztc0Owys8 IF you follow these tutorials you can build those shader yourselves or download them from Blender Market I think

Comment: Also ... with B2M you can simply download a non-seamless image texture somewhere, make it seamless, create the other maps, then import these maps in Blender and connect them to the PBR Shaders. I think that is cool

Comment: That's interesting, but I think you should name your texture nodes to help people understanding what they are (color, spec, normal, metallic mask). This would make your screenshot more readable.

Comment: @bithur That is a good tip !!! I update my answer later with your recommendations.

Comment: @OldMan Good question, but still a bad answer. Did you wrote that for your own? Can you make it more useful to others? Are you going to edit it?

Comment: @brockmann this is a very generic comment you make. What is your question ? Have you read my answers to your earlier question ?